# How can I change language programmatically for fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, locale, android-resources

I change locale this way.

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(updateResources(base, sessionInteractor.locale))
}

fun updateResources(context: Context, locale: Locale): Context {

        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val resources = context.resources
        val config = Configuration(resources.configuration)

        config.setLocale(locale)
        return context.createConfigurationContext(config)
}
```

It's perfect works for activities but doesn't work for fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh the fragment after setting the locale. The language won't change if you don't recreate an `Activity`, similarly, refresh a `Fragment` like this:

```
Fragment frag = null;
frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.detach(frag);
fragmentTransaction.attach(frag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

If there's no tag in your fragment, add the following code:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_id, fragment, "Your_Fragment_TAG").commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: I restart app after change language because I need to change language on google map. Is it possible to apply your solution to Navigation component?

Comment: Yes it's applicable if you're using Navigation Component as well because for example, `NavHostFragment` is also a Fragment.